# Local host page not found

Tags: django, django-models, localhost, http-status-code-404

Okay so I am a new learner and am following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6esTdOLXh4

My problem is that the last part of that video shows a posting site's posts when you click the  linking to the post:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/posts/details/1%3E/
Using the URLconf defined in djangoproject1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='index']
details/<int:id>/ [name='details']
admin/
posts/ [name='index']
posts/ details/<int:id>/ [name='details']
The current path, posts/details/1>/, didn't match any of these.
```

Here's the .py and .html files that I  was editing that may be the best place to search for errors

posts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('details/<int:id>/', views.details, name='details')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Posts

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    # return HttpResponse('HELLO FROM POSTS')

    # allows post to be shown in posts connected to index.html/
    posts = Posts.objects.all()[:10]

    context = {
        'title': 'Latest Posts',
        'posts': posts
    }

    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)

def details(request, id):
    post = Posts.objects.get(id=id)

    context = {
        'post': post
    }

return render(request, 'posts/details.html', context)
```

details.html

```
{% extends 'posts/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h3 class="center-align red lighten-3">{{post.title}}</h3>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
        {{post.body}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
        {{post.created_at}}       
    </div>
</div>
<a href="/posts" class="btn">Go Back</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: The question was why I was getting the error at the top. All good now though, thanks.

Comment: @StormLlamas did my answer work for you. If so can you check mark it. Thanks!

Comment: @StormLlamas can you checkmark my question if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @AgentLu oh. no. I posted an answer of my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the answer and it was just a typo of "s" in my index.py file

```
{% extends 'posts/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h3 class="center-align red lighten-3">{{title}}</h3>
<ul class="collection">
    <!-- allows post to be shown in posts connected to views.py/ -->
    {% for post in posts %}
        <li class="collection-item"><a href="/posts/details/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

the before was:

```
<a href="/post/details/{{posts.id}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the ">" symbol from the link. You urls, do not contain the ">" symbol and only have a number. Therefore, the link you put into the url does not connect with any of your links in your urls.py. You could also add a seperate link in urls.py that includes the ">" but I do not think that you want to do that. 
Let me know if this works!

You new link would be:

//localhost:8000/posts/details/1/

Comment: Thanks, yes I wanted to get that solved, but I thought it was a just an inconsequential bug or something and I believe it was. The code wasn't asking for a ">" anyway.

Comment: @StormLlamas Can you check mark my answer if it helped you? Thanks!